# Why is it "dirigeant" and not "dirigeur"?

Tags: étymologie

The pattern for forming agent nouns usually seems to be dropping the ending from the infinitive and adding "eur" or "euse," such as *chanteur*, *accusateur*, *procureur.* However, some verbs instead take "-ant", such as *étudiant* and *dirigeant*.

Is there any rule for this, or etymological explanation? Is it arbitrary?

Comment: As far as I know there is no rule for this. I think it has to do with the fact that _étudiant_ and _dirigeant_ are "classes" of people, who are defined by the fact that they are study_ing_ or direct_ing_ at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-eur/1) has a full paragraph (Rem. gen. 3) explaining the generic difference between adjectives and substantives in *-ant* vs the ones in *-eur*.

The main idea is that *-eur* generally implies a function (intrinsic role) while *-ant* is more a property (activity).

One example would be the opposition between *c'est un gagneur* (he is a winner) and *c'est un gagnant* (he is one of the winners).

So the *étudiants* and *dirigeants* happen to study or manage more likely because they decided or were told or elected to do so while a *chanteur* an *accusateur* or a *procureur* have completed studies or trainings in order to sing or prosecute as their main occupation.

As dimitris suggested, a *doctorant* is studying (transient activity) while a *docteur* is a permanent title and *chercheurs* have decided to make research their main long term activity.

Note that the distinction is not always manifest, e.g.:

- *Attaquant* (striker) vs *défenseur* (defender)
- *Voyant(e)* (psychic) vs *voyeur*

Comment: I think the main pattern applies with étudiant doctorant,  docteur (en mécanique for instance) et chercheur  post-doctoral, non ?

Comment: Pour réponses comme celle-ci, FSE est vraiment indispensable ☺. Merci pour avoir rajouter mon commentaire.

Comment: La différence entre gagneuse et gagnante est encore plus frappante ;-)

Comment: @LaurentS. La différence est frappeuse ;-)